# Writing and polishing a CSV parser

Tags: c#, parsing

As part of a recent project I had to read and write from a CSV file and put in a grid view in c#. In the end decided to use a ready built parser to do the work for me.

Because I like to do that kind of stuff, I wondered how to go about writing my own.

So far all I've managed to do is this:

```
//Read the header
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dialog.FileName);
            string row = reader.ReadLine();
            string[] cells = row.Split(',');

            //Create the columns of the dataGridView
            for (int i = 0; i < cells.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                column.Name = cells[i];
                column.HeaderText = cells[i];
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
            }

            //Display the contents of the file
            while (reader.Peek() != -1)
            {
                row = reader.ReadLine();
                cells = row.Split(',');
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cells);
            }
```

My question: is carrying on like this a wise idea, and if it is (or isn't) how would I test it properly?

Comment: You'll have to change the method of splitting a row into cells if you want to support files containing string values with commas.

Comment: You can use the recommandable VB.NET [TextFieldParserClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6.aspx) even in C#.

Comment: Well, you don't handle values that are wrapped in quotes.  You don't handle new lines or commas within values wrapped in quotes, you don't handle the case where any row has more columns than the first row.  Unless there is some compelling reason not to, I'd stick with the library tools for this so you don't need to worry about edge cases such as these.

Comment: @Servy this is just a 'learning exercise' in my own time, as I said - I  used a library.

Comment: My point is that even if it is just an exercise, a part of that would be implementing that functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a programming exercise (for learning and gaining experience) it is probably a very reasonable thing to do.  For production code, it may be better to use an existing library mainly because the work is already done.  There are quite a few things to address with a CSV parser.  For example (randomly off the top of my head):

- Quoted values (strings)
- Embedded quotes in quoted strings
- Empty values (NULL ... or maybe even NULL vs. empty).
- Lines without the correct number of entries
- Headers vs. no headers.
- Recognizing different data types (e.g., different date formats).

If you have a very specific input format in a very controlled environment, though, you may not need to deal with all of those.

Comment: Thank you! This is just an exercise for myself - I'd definitely use an existing library for production code!

Comment: In that case I think it is a great project to work on. It has a number of things to learn about but is not overwhelmingly large.

Answer (score 3):

> ... is carrying on like this a wise idea ...?

Since you're doing this as a learning exercise, you may want to dig deeper into [lexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) theory. Your current approach will show its shortcomings fairly quickly as described in [Stop Rolling Your Own CSV Parser!](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp). It's not that parsing CSV data is difficult. (It's not.) It's just that most CSV parser projects treat the problem as a text splitting problem versus a parsing problem. If you take the time to define the CSV "language", the parser almost writes itself.

[RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) defines a grammar for CSV data in [ABNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABNF) form:

```
file = [header CRLF] record *(CRLF record) [CRLF]
header = name *(COMMA name)
record = field *(COMMA field)
name = field
field = (escaped / non-escaped)
escaped = DQUOTE *(TEXTDATA / COMMA / CR / LF / 2DQUOTE) DQUOTE
non-escaped = *TEXTDATA
COMMA = %x2C
CR = %x0D ;as per section 6.1 of RFC 2234
DQUOTE =  %x22 ;as per section 6.1 of RFC 2234
LF = %x0A ;as per section 6.1 of RFC 2234
CRLF = CR LF ;as per section 6.1 of RFC 2234
TEXTDATA =  %x20-21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-7E
```

This grammar shows how single characters are built up to create more and more complex language elements. (As written, definitions go the opposite direction from complex to simple.)

If you start with a grammar, you can write parsing functions that mirror non-terminal grammar elements (the lowercase items). Julian M Bucknall describes the process in [Writing a parser for CSV data](http://www.boyet.com/articles/csvparser.html). Take a look at [Test-Driven Development with ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Test-Driven+Development+with+ANTLR) for an example of the same process using a parser generator.

Keep in mind, there is no one accepted CSV definition. CSV data in the wild is not guaranteed to implement all of the RFC 4180 suggestions.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. I didn't want an unwieldy switch statement with lots of String.Split() calls. That's why I stopped where I did!

Answer (score 2):

Get (or make) some CSV data and write [Unit Tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) using [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) or [Visual Studio Testing Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/visual-studio-testing-tools).

Be sure to test edge cases like

```
"csv","Data","with","a","trailing","comma",
```

and

```
"csv","Data","with,","commas","and","""quotes""","in","it"
```

Answer (score 0):

This come from
http://www.gigawebsolution.com/Posts/Details/61/Building-a-Simple-CSV-Parser-in-C#

```
public interface ICsvReaderWriter
{
    List<string[]> Read(string filePath, char delimiter);
    void Write(string filePath, List<string[]> lines, char delimiter);
}

public class CsvReaderWriter : ICsvReaderWriter
{
    public List<string[]> Read(string filePath, char delimiter)
    {
        var fileContent = new List<string[]>();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.Unicode))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                {
                    fileContent.Add(line.Split(delimiter));
                }
            }
        }
        return fileContent;
    }

    public void Write(string filePath, List<string[]> lines, char delimiter)
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true, Encoding.Unicode))
        {
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var data = line.Aggregate(string.Empty,
                                         (current, column) => current +
                                          string.Format("{0}{1}", column,delimiter))
                    .TrimEnd(delimiter);
                writer.WriteLine(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Careful, this doesn't work for fields with embedded newlines, fields containing the delimiter as a literal, and quote-enclosed fields.

Answer (score -1):

Parsing a CSV file isn't difficult, but it involves more than simply calling `String.Split()`.

You are breaking the lines at each comma. But it's possible for fields to contain embedded commas. In these cases, CSV wraps the field in double quotes. So you must also look for double quotes and ignore commas within those quotes. In addition, it's even possible for fields to contain embedded double quotes. Double quotes must appear within double quotes and be "doubled up" to indicate the quote is a literal character.

If you'd like to see how I did it, you can check out [this article](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/files/reading-and-writing-csv-files-in-c).