# How to store multiple datatype values into single list without defining class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, webapi

**Expected result :**

```
List<something> obj = new List<something>(); //something is i need.
string[] val = new string[] {"hi","20"}; //here I used static but input data fetch from CSV file. So we don't know when which type of data will come?.
int intval;
for(int i=0;i<val.Length;i++)
{
      if(int.TryParse(val[i],out intval)
      {
          obj.add(intval);   //here I face the error "Cannot implicitly convert int to string"
      }
      else
      {
          obj.add(val[i]);
      }
}
```

---

I need to add int value and also string value into the same list. But The condition is Developer don't know when which type of value will come. So here I used `TryParse` to convert values and store into list.

---

**How to declare a list or any other methods are there?**

**`Note: Don't use Class to declare field and define like List<classname> val = new List<classname>();`**

Comment: What you probably want is `List<object> obj = new List<object>();`, because `string` and `int` both inherit from the base `Object` type.

Comment: But after convert the value using ```TryParse``` it return only a value. but how to add value into the object list. I tried this it shows ```Cannot implicitly convert INT to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>'```

Comment: Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9266846/2791540) which describes why it isn't the best idea to write your own CSV parser.

Comment: Give several examples of CSV files you will encounter

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `List<object>`. Every type ultimately derives from `object`:

```
List<object> obj = new List<object>();

string[] val = new string[] {"hi","20"};

for(int i = 0; i < val.Length; i++)
{
      if(int.TryParse(val[i], out var intval)
      {
          obj.add(intval);
      }
      else
      {
          obj.add(val[i]);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do this but I think the code below is what you're looking for. I suppose you can later check if each list value typeof is string/int but why store multi value types in one list like this?

```
string[] val = new string[] { "hi", "20" };
List<object> objs = val.Select(x =>
{
    if (int.TryParse(x, out var intval))
       return (object)intval;
    else
       return (object)x;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: My Task :
Read CSV file and insert the columns and values to the ```DataTable``` after insert I need to summarize the integer column in the table based on the distinct value of FirstColumn. So i try to read the CSV file it returns the string array so I split with ```,``` and insert all the values into the ```DataTable``` so. Before I insert data into the ```DataTable``` I want to convert the value when integer value will come. so do like this.

Comment: @yuvarajanbazhagan Have you considered using a library, such as `CsvHelper`?

Comment: No Third party library used here. File.IO used

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to store all the results that you get to a single list without caring about the type then dont Parse to int type like

```
 for (int i = 0; i < val.Length; i++)
{
      //simply add the 
          obj.add(val[i]);
      
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I Need to both type of data. INT value and also String value is required.

Comment: C# is strongly typed so that situation of storing both on the same list is impossible, however you could use a Dictionary. where you store the value as string and type then you can query by type later if you so need

var dict = new Dictionary<string, Type>() {
.     { "10",10.GetType()},
. };
> dict.Where(x=>x.Value==10.GetType()).ToList()
List<KeyValuePair<string, Type>>(1) { { "10", [System.Int32] } }

Comment: here I couldn't use any values for key. Suppose I use Key it will create more problem in retrieve the data as per my condition.

Comment: Use the raw value from val[i] as the key to the dictionary, then for the value (Type), try parse to check whether its an integer or string....when finally you want to save information you can separate by type

Comment: Okay i will try this method.

Comment: let me know how it goes